# What does 色々と何ですから mean here?

Tags: translation

```
ここでは色々と何ですから
宿屋で お待ちいただけますか？
```

I understand that the speaker doesn't want to talk here and asks to wait at the inn. But I can't fully understand this part 色々と何ですから. Does it mean that the speaker has various reasons not to talk here, but he doesn't want to elaborate?

Comment: Is this exactly as the text appeared in the source? If you can, please copy and paste it, if not at least check.

Comment: Yes, that is exact text, no mistake here. It's from the video game "Grandia 2". The speaker is priest.